# How can Rey and others understand BB-8 in the Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, languages, the-force-awakens, droids

Spoilers regarding Rey and BB-8 from *The Force Awakens* below:

It seems like everyone can suddenly understand droid speak (from at least BB-8) in *The Force Awakens*. If I remember correctly, from the moment Rey comes in contact with BB-8, she seems to be able to comprehend the droid (more than just understanding intonation, but actually understanding specific “thoughts” the droid is communicating through bleeps and bloops).

**How is this possible?**

Wouldn’t a translator of some sort be needed unless there was deep familiarity between the droid/human, or only basic intonations or feelings were being communicated? (see [this related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/how-do-people-understand-astromech-droids/106460#106460) about understanding astromech droids, where all the answers seem to cite this sort of situation).

Comment: Well, I can confirm 100% from novelization she understands his beeps. No details on how, yet

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found the answer in the Alan Dean Foster novelization (all quotes form there unless otherwise stated).

Not **everyone** understands BB-8. Finn **does not**. So it's plausible that Rey - being mechanically gifted scavenger - learned Binary (***UPDATE***: TFA Visual Dictionary Data explicitly includes **a snippet that Rey had contact with off-worlders and learned Binary from them**).

> “Okay, look—we have to know the location of the Resistance base. You
>   heard Rey. She thinks she can get us there—but you have to tell us
>   where it is.” **The droid emitted a flurry of rapid, soft beeps. An
>   impatient Finn waved them off.**
>
> **“I don’t speak that, but I think I got the gist**. You just accused me
>   of not being with the Resistance, didn’t you?”

This theory is confirmed kinda, because **Chewie** can talk to BB-8:

> Striding effortlessly alongside, Chewbacca groaned assent. Behind
>   Finn, **BB-8 beeped a question to which the Wookiee readily replied.
>   Droid and Wookiee then entered into a rapid-fire conversation, the
>   sound of which made Finn’s head hurt**.

Obviously, Poe - who was a pilot with BB-8 as his astromech, was a good candidate to understand him. Yep.

> “I wasn’t dead, just momentarily out of it,” the pilot explained.
>   “Came around long enough to see that you had got out. Pulled out of
>   the dive just long enough to set down—hard. Impact threw me clear.
>   Woke up at night; no you, no ship, no nothing. Went looking—in the
>   wrong direction. Got picked up by some itinerant trader.” He grinned.
>   “Tell you all about it sometime.” **A plaintive beep caused him to
>   turn and look down. “Beebee-Ate says that you saved him.”**

However, we know that almost nobody understands R2-D2: Luke barely does (he needs X-Wing translation in canon); Leia doesn’t understand R2-D2 in TFA either (and neither, seemingly, does Poe who translates for BB-8 but not R2-D2, who needs C-3PO’s translation)

> An excited Leia moved closer. Of all the organics in the room, no one
>   had a more personal relationship to the little droid than she did.
>   **“What’s he saying?” she asked.**
>
> **The protocol droid explained**. “If the information you are seeking was in the Imperial archives, he believes he may have cataloged that
>   data. He’s scanning through it now.”
>
> Rey stared at the diminutive droid. “Artoo has the rest of the map?”
>   “He’s certainly implying the possibility!” C-3PO told her. “I’ve never
>   heard him beep with this much energy before.”
>
> Emitting a long, sustained whistle, R2-D2 projected a full
>   three-dimensional image of a huge navigational star chart. No one in
>   the room could fail to notice that it was missing a substantial
>   fragment. In response to the hovering image, **BB-8 began beeping
>   excitedly.   “Yeah, buddy, hold on,” Poe told him. “I have it.”**

Now, this all doesn’t explain the **how**.

However, we know from novelization that BB-8 spoke DIFFERENT droid languages - perhaps one variant was more understandable to organics?

> In the dark, dusty storeroom he rolled over to the R2 unit and beeped
>   a greeting, the transmission sequence too rapid and too exhaustive for
>   any human to follow. It didn’t matter. There was no response from the
>   immobile R2 unit.
>
> **BB-8 tried again, utilizing a different droid language.** When that also failed, he moved forward and gave the other mechanical a forceful
>   nudge. Like everything else, that too failed to generate a response.

We also know that his primary language is related to standard Binary but is a more evolved generation of it, which may go a long way to explaining why many people understand it.

> 27th generation droid-speak code, a compressed variant of the most common astromech language *(source: TFA Visual Dictionary, or [SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111411/976))*

Comment: It was also CLEAR in the film that finn could not understand BB8, On the note of droid languages the beeps BB8 defaultwise produces are QUITE different in tone and pronounciation than what R2 produces thus it sounds like completely different dialects (C3PO also mentions something in ANH that some droids have a quite......bad dialect of sorts). +1 btw

Comment: Pssst, her name is R**e**y.

Comment: @CreationEdge Spelling, grammar - A Jedi craves not these things

Comment: I pictured you more as a Sith!

Comment: @CreationEdge - [Aing-Tii](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aing-Tii), rather

Comment: "Droid and Wookiee then entered into a rapid-fire conversation, the sound of which made Finn’s head hurt." — so I guess the next question is "How can BB-8 understand Chewbacca?"

Comment: @Nefrubyr - he understands Basic so natural language understanding is there. A modern Earth smartphone is at the point where it can understand several hundred languages, easily, and that's BEFORE understanding natural language on astromech droid level. Adding a couple extra dictionaries is a miniscule upgrade by comparison.

Comment: @DVK Can you include a quote of the snip from TFA Visual Dictionary Data that you mention in your update, and maybe clarify where your quotes come from? (I know I'm being picky). Great response though, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in the in-universe factbook ['Star Wars: Rey's Survival Guide'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rey's_Survival_Guide).

Over the years Rey has salvaged a large number of computer cores which she uses for entertainment and as part of her survival regime. This includes flight simulators, the technical schematics for a wide range of Empire, Republic and Rebellion-era ships and, crucially, the Star Wars equivalent of language tapes. It seems that learning to speak alien languages and droidspeak gives her a substantial edge as a scavenger.

> **What do I do when I'm home?** Mostly, I refurbish gear at my workbench -
>   it costs too much to make extensive repairs at Unkar's washing tables
>   in Niima. I have an old Y-wing computer display I use to study
>   schematics of rebel and Imperial starships and run flight sims. **I
>   practice alien languages and droidspeak so I can talk to people in
>   Niima.** And I sleep - I made myself a hammock when I was just a kid. At
>   first it was huge, and I would feel lost in the middle of it. Now it
>   fits more snugly.

Answer (score 1):

Rey may have **used the *Force* to read the mind of** and understand BB-8. For example, she was able to read the mind of Kylo Ren in the "Mind-Force War" scene. It wasn't easy though. If she was able to do a task like that, then an untrained Force level so high, may have easily read the mind of a droid. Therefore, she understood what BB-8 was saying.

Another idea I have is that **droid language was taught, or picked up** from companionship with droids. However, Finn couldn't have learned (or picked up) the language because his job was sanitation, so he may have only been taught about, well, sanitation. Rey may not have gotten an education on droids, after being kidnapped onto the desert planet at such a young age. Therefore, we do not know if there were schools. However, Rey may have been taught it after working with and selling technical things, so she was more likely to have interacted with droids.

Comment: Does the Force work on droids?

Comment: Do droids have minds?

Answer (score -2):

Y'all forgot who built c3p0 . A protocol driod . Anakin did. And I don't remember Anakin needing it uless he is flying a fighter then it is displayed.  Anakin had to have some great understanding of binary if he to build C3p0 originally to help his mom . And Luke could understand r2d2 . Remember him cleaning r2d2 then the hologram of Leia is displayed then finding out about old Ben Kenobi. Then about Rey in ep7 their could be familiar traits between her and Anakin to Luke strength in the force. Mechanical knowledge. Pilot skills ..  the reflexes see things before they happen listen to qun jinn in ep 1 . Explaining the force to Anakin s mother.

Comment: Could you make this a bit more clear?

Comment: Knowledge of languages is not passed down genetically, it is something that has to be learned through experience. I think it's possible to inherit a knack for picking up languages, but without ever being exposed to a language there's still no way to learn it. Also, how does your answer explain how Chewie or others can speak to BB-8?